# Generate a parser enabling incremental API and inspection API

Tags: ocaml, menhir, ocaml-dune, merlin

I have a big project built by menhir and traditional makefile. First, I wanted to add a mechanism of error handling like [this project](https://gitlab.inria.fr/fpottier/menhir/-/tree/master/demos/calc-syntax-errors) to my project.

By following the [dune](https://gitlab.inria.fr/fpottier/menhir/-/blob/master/demos/calc-syntax-errors/dune) of the sample project, I managed to generate `.mly`, `.mli`, `.ml`, `.cmi` and `.cmo` of `unitActionsParser_e.mly` by the following commands:

```
$ menhir --only-preprocess-u parser_e.mly > unitActionsParser_e.mly
$ menhir --table --external-tokens Parser_e unitActionsParser_e.mly
$ ocamlfind ocamlc -package menhirLib -c unitActionsParser_e.mli
```

And the incremental API and error handling did work.

Then, I wanted to add error recovery like [this project](https://github.com/yurug/menhir-error-recovery) to my project. Then, `items state` raised an error `Error: Unbound value items` in my project. Based on the [manual](http://gallium.inria.fr/%7Efpottier/menhir/manual.html#sec%3Ainspection) and the [dune](https://github.com/yurug/menhir-error-recovery/blob/master/dune), I guess I need to add `--inspection` somewhere.

I tried `menhir --explain --inspection --table --dump --infer --external-tokens Parser_e unitActionsParser_e.mly`, then `camlfind ocamlc -package menhirLib -c unitActionsParser_e.mli` raised an error `Unbound type constructor Parser_e.terminal`.

I also tried to directly work on `parser_e.mly` rather than using `unitActionsParser_e` by `menhir --explain --inspection --table --dump --infer parser_e.mly`, but it returned an error `Unbound module Utility` where `Utility` is a module in another folder needed by `parser_e.mly`. After I manually copied `utility.cm*` to the folder of `parser_e.mly`, it returned an error `Unbound module Sedlexing` (here is [a fork](https://github.com/SoftTimur/menhir-error-recovery) where we can reproduce the error) (this is probably related to [Interaction with build systems of the manual](http://gallium.inria.fr/%7Efpottier/menhir/manual.html#sec91)).

Does anyone know what are the correct commands and flags to generate a parser (either `UnitActionsParser_e` or `Parser_e`) enabling incremental API and inspection API of menhir?

(* link in discuss.ocaml.org: https://discuss.ocaml.org/t/generate-a-parser-enabling-incremental-api-and-inspection-api/9380 *)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is indeed related to the [interaction of menhir and build systems](http://gallium.inria.fr/%7Efpottier/menhir/manual.html#sec95). Precisely, the inspection API (`--inspection`) requires the type information of `.mly` (including its semantic actions) to be known. I chose to directly work on `parse_e.mly` rather than `unitActionsParser_e.mly`, and followed the approach of "Obtaining OCaml type information without calling the OCaml compiler":

- `menhir --explain --inspection --table --dump --infer-write-query mockfile.ml parser_e.mly` to generate `mockfile.ml`
- `ocamlfind ocamlc -I lib -package sedlex -package menhirLib -i mockfile.ml > sigfile` to generate `sigfile`. Note that `-I lib` refers to the directory of external modules, their `.cm[io]` files should be ready to use.
- `menhir --explain --inspection --table --dump --infer-read-reply sigfile parser_e.mly` to generate especially `parser_e.ml`, `parser_e.mli`, `.conflicts` and `automaton`.

As a result, `parser_e.ml` contains more type information and the inspection API is in `Parser_e.MenhirInterpreter`.